# returns [object DOMWindow] instead of user input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

ive been writing a website for about 3 days and i ran into a problem. i have a textfield that changes a span on the page using javascript, and this works fine on firefox and ie. but on google chrome it just returns "[object DOMWindow]" no mater what i change. the code is way to long to post so i would just like to ask if anyone knows what causes this?

[image]

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ at least and post the *relevant* part the code and/or try to reproduce the problem with a smaller code base. It is impossible for us to help you otherwise.

Comment: post your java script instead of the image

Comment: There is simply not enough information in the question without seeing _some_ code. Any chance you can at least provide a live link to the site, or some sort of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Maybe you're returning the textfield object instead of the textfield value. It's just a guess, but it's difficult without code.

Comment: @Matt: +1 for SSCCE, I have seen it before, now I should bookmark it ;)

Comment: You're probably using the keyword `this` in or from the incorrect scope.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess without seeing code would be you're using the `this` keyword, which behaves differently in different browsers. `this` refers to the `window` element any time that it is not in a different context. Check to make sure you are either using a library that normalizes the `this` keyword (like jQuery) or are explicitly getting the text field every time.

Comment: i used document.getElementById("toptext").value; to get the value of the text field

Comment: The only situation where `this` differs across browser is that in an event handler attached with `attachEvent`, `this` refers to the window, not the DOM element. Apart from that, `this` works the same everywhere.

Comment: Did you use the keyword `this` anywhere in the code? The value of an element won't return `[object DOMWindow]` unless you inputted it yourself.

Comment: @givaway, well, without seeing at least the code where this value is getting returned from, I'm not sure I can help much.

Comment: @Felix Kling, without seeing his code, I was assuming it was event driven, especially considering it was a text input based question, which was why I stated that `this` is treated differently. Also, if you try to alert the window, or `toString` it, it will return that value.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to relax your statement a bit. It sounded like `this` is unpredictable and behaves differently in every browser. Afaik, the difference I mentioned is the only one.

Comment: well iv looked and i didnt see any reason why it should be wrong so i changed the way i retrieved text from user input. thanks for all your help, really appreciated